# Which of these (Antec vs Seasonic) PSU's should I go for

Tags: power-supply, smps

So, I'm looking to buy a new PSU. After much research and a few other questions on this forum, I've come up with this shortlist of PSUs.

http://amzn.in/akQKpXE

The PSUs in the list are as follows

- Seasonic S12II 520W - INR: 6,500.00 (USD:101.29)
- Seasonic S12II 430W - INR: 5,500.00 (USD: 85.71)
- Antec VP500PC - INR: 3,630.0 (USD: 56.57)
- Antec VP450P - INR: 3,700.00 (USD: 57.66)
- Antec VP550P -INR: 4,755.00 (USD: 74.10)

The Antec ones fit perfectly in my budget and needs, however, I see a much better opinion regarding Seasonic. Seasonic is slightly out of my budget, however, I'm willing to stretch only and only if there's something absolutely additional that I would gain from it.

**My main requirement or criteria (in order of priority) are as follows**

**1. Safety:** Certainty that the PSU won't cause any damage to other components within the system if at all it were to fail OR if there are some irregularities from the wall outlet. (I live in an area that is prone to voltage fluctuations. I currently use a UPS but still, additional safety would mean a lot).

**2. Durability/Stability:** It would maintain decent performance for a good amount of time, at least 2-3 years.

That's all I'm really bothered about. Safety of all my other components being the most important one of all. I really don't mind a bit of noise from the fan, unsleeved cables, or anything else that does not directly impact performance (consistent output) and safety( being most important of all).

I'm also not going to overclock the system in any way. If anything, I might add an additional stick RAM somewhere next year.

**So my question is,**

- Does the Antec suffice for the above requirement, if yes, which would be the best of the three. (I'm inclinded on VP450P, don't really know what the "C" in VP500PC represents. I heard the "PC" suffixed ones are made by CWT, while the "P" suffixed ones are made by FSP/Delta seems to be some confusion regarding it).
- If not, will the Seasonic 430W unit suffice for the below config (as I'm not looking at overclocking or expanding in the near future. Apart from RAM).
- I know Seasonic uses better components (mostly Japanese capacitors) and makes it own PSUs (as well as for other brands). However, how exactly does this impact the quality? I mean are non-Japanese components more prone to burst/explosions, or lesser quality voltage regulation, more ripple etc. Basically what exactly is it, that I'm putting at stake if I go for Antec instead of Seasonic. I ask this as I want to keep a balance between keeping my costs low and not compromising on anything absolutely necessary.

**My current rig is as follows**

- Motherboard: Asus H81M-CS
- Processor: i5-4440 3.1Ghz
- Ram: Kingston hyperx fb-dimm
- SSD: Kingston SSDNow 300 (128GB)
- HDD: WD 1TB
- Graphics Card: GTX 750Ti

Online PSU calculators say I need roughly 300W adding buffer I think a 450 - 550 should be fine.

*Feel free to recommend anything else you think might fit the above requirements and be cheaper than the ones on my list if any*

Comment: Do you specifically want one of these brands or can I suggest an alternative along with the best option from the list?

Comment: @EdwardNunn I'm very much open to alternatives! Infact that would help me, even more, incase I missed out on something good